# Ajax PHP Created Form Not Submitting

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a set of three combo boxes (drop downs) that are populated by PHP with values from a database. I've tested these combo boxes by changing the echoed Submit button to `type='submit'`, and loading the php page itself. They work without a hitch in this fashion.

However, when I load the Ajax page, the submit button refuses to trigger the Ajax function. I have tested the page by creating a set of static combo boxes with html, and in this case the Ajax fires without a hitch. Yet using the PHP created combo boxes do not trigger the Ajax.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what the problem is concerning my code.

**The HTML & jQuery:**

```
<div id="gallery_container">
    <ul class="new_arrivals_gallery"></ul>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender){
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "filter_test.php",
            data: {imgFamily:imgFamily, imgClass:imgClass, imgGender:imgGender},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#gallery_container").html(data);
            },
        });
    }
    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results

    //Bind keypress event to Ajax call
    $('.filter').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
            var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
            var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
            //Fetch the images
            loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
        }
    });

    //Bind the click event to Ajax call on submit
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
        var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
        var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
        //Fetch the images
        loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
    })
});
```

**The PHP (Although I don't believe the problem lies here):**

*I'm showing only one combo box to save space, and since they're all the same*

```
// Queries for combo boxes
$imgFamily_query = "SELECT DISTINCT imgFamily FROM images WHERE $clause";
$imgClass_query = "SELECT DISTINCT imgClass FROM images WHERE $clause";
$imgGender_query = "SELECT DISTINCT imgGender FROM images WHERE $clause";


// Create the form and combo boxes
echo "<form name='refine' action=''>
        <fieldset><legend>Refine Results</legend>";

    // imgFamily combo box
    if($imgFamily_result = mysql_query($imgFamily_query))  {
      if($imgFamily_success = mysql_num_rows($imgFamily_result) > 0) {
        // Start combo-box
        echo "<label for='imgFamily' id='imgFamily_label'>Choose a family</label>\n
            <select class='filter' id='imgFamily' name='imgFamily'>\n
            <option value='1'></option>\n";
        // For each item in the results...
        while ($imgFamily_row = mysql_fetch_array($imgFamily_result))
          // Add a new option to the combo-box
          echo "<option value='$imgFamily_row[imgFamily]'>$imgFamily_row[imgFamily]</option>\n";
        // End the combo-box
        echo "</select>\n";
      } else { echo "No results found."; }
    } else { echo "Failed to connect to database."; }


    // Add a submit button to the form
    echo "</fieldset>
        <fieldset><input type='button' name='submit' value='submit' id='submit'></fieldset>
    </form>";
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Looks like a code smell to me..
You should post only the relevant code you believe causes the issue. It's hard to follow your code.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "when I load the Ajax page" because isn't your problem that it's NOT loading when you click submit? Also, have you tried also binding a simple function, like "alert('test');" to the listener so you know that it works?

Comment: @Callie What I mean by "when I load the Ajax page" is when I load the page that contained the Ajax as opposed to the page that contains the PHP. I have not tried to place any alert functions into my code. Where would you suggest I attempt that?

Comment: Only 2 answers accepted out of the last 9 question?

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour If you take a look at said questions, you will see why. Those questions were not answered in a complete way. I always understood accepted answer to be an indication of a correct and complete answer.

Comment: @Majid I had to wait to select my answers on those questions as the correct one. I just went back and did it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @stefmikhail - good for everybody! I hope I have not sounded rude.

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour - Not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert the form and thereby overwrite the elements to which the submit-event is bound. You should re-execute the code that binds the events after you have inserted the new form.

A cleaner way would be to return a JSON object or XML containing just the modified information, and update your current form instead of inserting a whole new one, but that will be more work.

```
function loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender){
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filter_test.php",
        data: {imgFamily:imgFamily, imgClass:imgClass, imgGender:imgGender},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#gallery_container").html(data);

            bindEvents(); // <---- Call it here
        },
    });
}

// Separate function
function bindEvents()
{
    //Bind keypress event to Ajax call
    $('.filter').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
            var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
            var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
            //Fetch the images
            loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
        }
    });

    //Bind the click event to Ajax call on submit
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
        var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
        var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
        //Fetch the images
        loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results

    bindEvents(); // <---- And here (where your code originally was).
});
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Should I only wrap the Ajax call itself in the document ready function?

Comment: Put the code that performs `$("#submit").click ... ` into a separate function. You can call that function from .ready, *and* after processing the Ajax request.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. Any chance you could edit your answer with an example?

Comment: Done. Moved the initialization code to the bindEvents function, which is called in two places. Also moved the loadData function, since it has not need being declared inside the .ready handler.

Comment: Ha I did it at the same time as you. Only I called my function `submit()` and I placed it in the Ajax `complete: function(){}`. Would that work as well? Or is success a better choice? In any case I'll be using your code as you made some other changes that make it better. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If both work, both are fine. But .success may be better, because that is the place where you modify the html, so that's the only time when you need to re-bind the events. You could also choose to add a `<script>` element in the returned html. This will be executed too on insertion. But I would choose for the solution I gave you.

Comment: Yes, I like this one better as well. Thanks for increasing my knowledge concerning Ajax. And you will notice I gave you a checkmark. Props to those who give correct answers!

Answer (score 2):

This is what is happening (basically a re-statement of what @GolezTrol is saying):

1. Your page finishes loading
2. loadData(1) is executed, but because it is an asynchronous call execution continues before form elements are fetched.
3. jquery executed `$('.filter').keypress(function(e)` but there are no elements with that class yet, so no binding takes place.
4. `$("#submit").click(function(){` has the same fate, we have no element with `submit` id yet.
5. response to ajax call arrives and `success` function adds the form elements to `gallery_container`, but there no bindings.

What you need to do is to call event binding functions when the respective elements have been added to the dom; so you should move them to after `$("#gallery_container").html(data);`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender){
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "filter_test.php",
            data: {imgFamily:imgFamily, imgClass:imgClass, imgGender:imgGender},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#gallery_container").html(data);
                //Bind keypress event to Ajax call
                $('.filter').keypress(function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
                        var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
                        var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
                        //Fetch the images
                        loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
                    }
                });

                //Bind the click event to Ajax call on submit
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                    var imgFamily = $('#imgFamily').attr('value');
                    var imgClass = $('#imgClass').attr('value');
                    var imgGender = $('#imgGender').attr('value');
                    //Fetch the images
                    loadData(imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! It's always nice when someone explains what's going so that I can understand better when dealing with future problems. Only problem now is figuring who to give the accepted answer to...

Comment: As I said this *is* based on GolezTrol's answer (the shorter one before edits). So, I'd say the accepted answer is correctly selected  right now.

Comment: That's mighty gracious of you. One quick question if you wouldn't mind. What does the `1` in `loadData(1)` mean? As well, what about the `e` in `function(e)` and `data` in `.html(data)`? Haven't been able to figure that one out yet.

Comment: Hummm ... now that you mention it, actually `loadData(1)` takes three parameters (`imgFamily, imgClass, imgGender`), when we call it that way, inside the function `imgFamily` will have a value of `1`, and the other two variables `imgClass` and `imgGender` will be undefined, so you are actually calling your php script will a url akin to `filter_test.php?imgFamily=imgFamily&imgClass=undefined&imgGender=undefined`. Why that causes no problem is because you are not accessing those parameters inside your php code. `e` is the keypress event we are passing to the function.

Comment: And `data` is what ajax call gets back from the server (the html that the php script generates).

Comment: Ahhh, I was wondering why on page load, the value of `imgFamily` was always coming through to the server as `1`. Now I know! So what would be a better thing to put into `loadData` instead of `1`? Also, am I correct in saying that in `html()`, I can put anything? That it doesn't have to be `data`?

Comment: @stefmikhail let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2926/discussion-between-majid-fouladpour-and-stefmikhail)

Comment: I just arrived at friends for dinner. I'll try to join you in a few.

Comment: No worries, I just followed SO's advice to avoid extended discussions in comments. My answer would be accessible through the link to the room, even if I'm not in there.