# Cant .ajax() submit a php form that has been loaded onto main page with jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having the following problem. Below is an explanation of what my PHP pages are and how they work. When I access form.php directly and try to submit it via AJAX, it works perfectly.

**Problem** - When I .load() form.php into main.php, none of the jQuery code within form.php fires. (verified through firebug) No submits, no alerts, nothing. How can I get the jQuery code within form.php to work when its loaded into main.php?

**main.php** -> This is the main PHP page which has a link on it. Once this link is clicked, the following jQuery code fires to load "form.php" within a div called #formcontainer. This is the code within main.php that loads form.php.

```
<a href="#" id="addHomeProfile">Foobar</a>
<div class="formcontainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addHomeProfile").click(function(){
      $(".formcontaineropen").load("form.php");
   });
});
</script>
```

**form.php** -> this is a form that gets loaded above. It submits data to MySQL through an jQuery .ajax() POST. Here is the jquery code which submits the form, which has an ID called #homeprofile.

```
<form id="homeprofile"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#homeprofile').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("form submitted");
        $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
           type: "POST",        
           url: 'update.php', 
           data: $('#homeprofile').serialize(),
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the alert show up?

Comment: Your form doesn't have a button, this makes it really hard to submit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax PHP Created Form Not Submitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217544/ajax-php-created-form-not-submitting)

Comment: Woops, sorry I forgot to add the <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> line in my code. The alert does not appear and the database call is not made. It appears that none of the jQuery code within form.php fires.

Comment: What you need to do is using `eval` on your ajax loaded jquery code. Since the return code is not evaluated by the JS engine the code will not be triggered.

Comment: use your script in head , you already mentioned it on document ready, put your code <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addHomeProfile").click(function(){
      $(".formcontaineropen").load("form.php");
   });
});
</script> in the head tag

Comment: The code is likely being executed too early. Add `console.log($('[id=homeprofile]').length)` to it to confirm  that you don't have duplicate id's and that the element exists when the code is executed.

Comment: @HamedMomeni That's not true. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for this like,

```
$(document).on('submit','#homeprofile',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert("form submitted");
    $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
       type: "POST", 
       url: 'update.php', 
       data: $('#homeprofile').serialize(),
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Just to note, I ended up moved this snippet of code into main.php, thus removing all jQuery code from form.php... Problem resolved!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `.on()` syntax for targeting dynamically created elements (elements loaded into the DOM by JS or jQuery after the initial rendering)

**Good**

```
// in english this syntax says "Within the document, listen for an element with id=homeprofile to get submitted"
$(document).on('submit','#homeprofile',function(e){

    //stop the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // put whatever code you need here

});
```

**Not as good**

```
// in english this syntax says "RIGHT NOW attach a submit listener to the element with id=homeprofile
// if id=homeprofile does not exist when this is executed then the event listener is never attached
$('#homeprofile').on('submit',function(e){

    //stop the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // put whatever code you need here

});
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation! This helped me to fully understand how to resolve the problem with the code that @Rohan Kumar provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Small issue is that you reference formcontaineropen in the jquery call (this is probably a typo?). The cause is that that a JS code loaded via AJAX will get interpreted (therefore eval() is not needed) but the document ready event will get triggered immediately (which may be before the AJAX loaded content is actually inserted and ready in the document - therefore the submit event may not bind correctly). Instead you need to bind your code to success of the AJAX request, something like this:

main.php:

```
<html>
<a href="#" id="addHomeProfile">Foobar</a>
<div class="formcontainer"></div>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addHomeProfile").click(function(){
      $(".formcontainer").load("form.php", '',
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            onLoaded();
        });
   });
});
</script>
```

form.php:

```
<form id="homeprofile"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoaded() {
    $('#homeprofile').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("form submitted");
        $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
           type: "POST",
           url: 'update.php',
           data: $('#homeprofile').serialize(),
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: the ready callback will be immediately executed since the dom is already ready. Your solution though would solve a possible race condition that could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is somewhat peculiar but anyhow here it is.

This would be your main.php:

```
<a href="#" id="addHomeProfile">Foobar</a>
<div class="formcontainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addHomeProfile").click(function(){
      $(".formcontaineropen").load("form.php", '', function(response){
           var res = $(response);
           eval($('script', res).html());
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

And this is your form.php:

```
<form id="homeprofile"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></form>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    $('#homeprofile').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("form submitted");
        $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
           type: "POST",        
           url: 'update.php', 
           data: $('#homeprofile').serialize(),
        });
    });

</script>
```